# Mysql query having same explain output performs differently in server and Locally

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

One of my select query behaves differently in server and local machine. In server it takes 15sec to complete where in local machine it takes only 0.297sec.

Kindly find the following screen shots of explain result from server and local machine. Both looks same.

[image: Explain result from local machine]

[image: Explain result from server]

See the profiler info below

[image: Profile info from Server]

[image: profile info from Local]

Which server parameters I need to check ?
Does the order of explain result has any impact in query performance?

### Create tables

```
CREATE TABLE `Exam_Registration` ( `examregnid` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `accountid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `examid` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `examtype` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1-Regular,2-Supply,3-Betterment,4 -Notional', `studentid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL, `colid` int(3) NOT NULL, `courseid` int(3) NOT NULL, `exrgstatus` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-Entry level,2-Apr by DEO,4-apr by Principal', `internal_mark_status` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1-Entry ,2-apr by DEO,3->apr by Principal', `csid` int(6) NOT NULL, `prjid` int(3) NOT NULL, `examregn_supply` int(6) DEFAULT NULL, `jr_appr_status` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1-Apr by JR', `examreg_type` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'T - Provisonal Registration,P-Permanent Registration', PRIMARY KEY (`examregnid`), KEY `Index_2` (`accountid`,`examregnid`,`examid`,`colid`,`csid`,`prjid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_3` (`accountid`), KEY `Index_4` (`examregnid`), KEY `Index_5` (`examid`), KEY `Index_6` (`colid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_7` (`csid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_8` (`exrgstatus`) USING BTREE) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1623337 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 
CREATE TABLE `student_exam_external` ( `stud_exm_ext_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `examid` int(11) NOT NULL, `examregnid` int(11) NOT NULL, `stud_paper_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '1 for internal only, 2 for external only, 3 for internal and external', `accountid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '1 for internal only, 2 for external only, 3 for internal and external', `subid` int(6) NOT NULL, `prent_abscent` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'P' COMMENT 'P for present, A for abscent', `falsenumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `generated_falsenumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `falsenumber_mapped_user` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, `falsenumber_mapped_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `falsenumber_map_status` int(2) unsigned DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0-not verified; 1 verified by ACO; 2 Verification failed; 3 duplicate entry; 4 infected barcode', `theory_ext_weighted_grade_point` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, `theory_ext_grade_point` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL, `theory_ext_grade` char(2) DEFAULT NULL, `theory_ext_grade_entred_user` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, `theory_ext_grade_entred_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `theory_ext_grade_status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL, `grade_verification` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'NULL- not verified, 1-ACO Verified, 2-CO Verified', `additional_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, `current_false_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`stud_exm_ext_id`), KEY `Index_5` (`examid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_6` (`subid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_7` (`examregnid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_8` (`accountid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_9` (`falsenumber`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_10` (`stud_paper_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_11` (`falsenumber_map_status`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_12` (`stud_exm_ext_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_13` (`stud_exm_ext_id`) USING BTREE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5464239 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `Qpcode_Master` ( `qpcode` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `examid` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `subid` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `semid` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `generated_date` datetime NOT NULL, `verification_status` int(1) NOT NULL, `approve_date` datetime NOT NULL, `qpid` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ug_qpcode` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`qpid`), UNIQUE KEY `Index_5` (`qpcode`,`examid`,`subid`), KEY `Index_6` (`examid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_7` (`qpcode`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_8` (`subid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_9` (`semid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=171008480 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
CREATE TABLE `camp_falseno_examiner_map` ( `cmpexm_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `camp_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL, `examid` int(6) DEFAULT NULL, `qpcode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `st_range` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `en_range` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `chief_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `additional_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `entered_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, `entered_datetime` datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`cmpexm_id`), KEY `Index_2` (`examid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_3` (`qpcode`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_4` (`st_range`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_5` (`en_range`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_6` (`camp_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_7` (`chief_code`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_8` (`additional_code`) USING BTREE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=227704 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;

CREATE TABLE `User_Details` ( `user_tbl_id` int(50) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `User_Id` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', `User_Type` char(8) NOT NULL, `User_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `Password_old` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `Status` char(1) NOT NULL, `Camp` varchar(4) NOT NULL, `college_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `prjid` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL, `colid` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL, `pwdstatus` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-pwd not changed 1 -pwd changed', `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, `emailstatus` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-email not updated 1 -email updated', PRIMARY KEY (`User_Id`,`user_tbl_id`) USING BTREE, UNIQUE KEY `Index_4` (`user_tbl_id`,`User_Id`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_3` (`user_tbl_id`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_5` (`User_Type`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_6` (`Status`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_7` (`User_Id`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_8` (`prjid`) USING BTREE, KEY `Index_9` (`colid`) USING BTREE) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=104180 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Query

```
SELECT  distinct
        SE.stud_exm_ext_id,SE.falsenumber,            
        concat(UD.User_Name, ' - ',UD.User_Id)additional,
        UD.User_Id,
SE.theory_ext_weighted_grade_point,
        SE.theory_ext_grade_point,
SE.theory_ext_grade,
        SE.grade_verification, SE.additional_code
    FROM  Exam_Registration E
    INNER JOIN  student_exam_external SE
            ON SE.examid=E.examid
      and  SE.examregnid=E.examregnid
      and  SE.accountid=E.accountid
      and  SE.examid=47
    inner join  Qpcode_Master QM  ON QM.examid=E.examid
      and  QM.examid=E.examid
      AND  QM.subid=SE.subid
      and  QM.examid=47
      and  QM.qpcode=21101986
    inner join  camp_falseno_examiner_map CFE
              ON CFE.qpcode=QM.qpcode
      AND  CFE.examid=SE.examid
      AND  CFE.examid=QM.examid
      and  CFE.examid=E.examid
      and  CFE.examid=47
      and  CFE.qpcode=21101986
      and  CFE.st_range<=SE.falsenumber
      and  CFE.en_range>=SE.falsenumber
    inner join  User_Details UD -- use index(Index_7,PRIMARY)
            ON UD.User_Id=CFE.additional_code
      and  UD.User_Id=SE.additional_code
      and  UD.prjid=2
    where  QM.qpcode=21101986
      and  SE.examid=47
      and  SE.falsenumber>=314465
      and  SE.falsenumber<=314566
      and  SE.theory_ext_weighted_grade_point is not null
    order by  SE.falsenumber;
```

Comment: *Both looks same.* ??? you do not see that the tables scanning order differs?

Comment: @Akina does 2000 more records affect performance?

Comment: *does 2000 more records affect performance?* What "2000 more records"? Formally - of course, the data array change MUST affect the performance.

Comment: How can I optimize it. Whether by adding a index or update system variable values

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE for all tables, complete query text and relevant data statistic. Also provide precise DBMS versions on local and remote nodes.

Comment: @Akina query added

Comment: The query contains a lot of conditions duplicates. The tables contains excess indices. The tables does not contain siutable indices. And I recommend you to write `student_exam_external` table as base one. [fiddle with formatted structures and query text](https://dbfiddle.uk/esd8LKXJ).

Answer (score 0):

Some of these **composite indexes** may help:

```
SE:  INDEX(examid, falsenumber)
UD:  INDEX(prjid, User_Id,  User_Name)
E:  INDEX(examid,  examregnid, accountid)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

My Index suggestions *may* help *both* servers to be faster.

**ON vs WHERE**: Use `ON` to say how the tables are 'related' (eg, `SE.accountid=E.accountid`); use `WHERE` for filtering (eg `SE.examid=47`).  For `INNER JOIN` it is redundant to put the same expression in both.

Since you have `ON CFE.qpcode=QM.qpcode`, there is no need to put `qpcode = 21101986` on both tables.  You have not declared them the same, but this may not be a problem.  (`SIGNED` vs `UNSIGNED`).

**Profile** is essentially useless.

Do the two servers have different sets of **data**?  Or at least different amounts of data?  That *could* explain the different results.

Convert all tables to InnoDB; **MyISAM is going away**.  Some of my advice above may be wrong (since it is predicated on InnoDB.)